Correct DAX syntax to create a column to subtract 2 dates in different tables
Hi I have table named:'reporting CC Admission' with a column called 'DateOfAdmissionToBH' and another table named 'column' with a column name 'DateOfReferral'.
I have tried using dateddiff to calculate the number of days from referral to admission and related but cannot get the syntax right.  Can anyone help please?  Do I need to join the tables to create the calculated column.

we'd probably need to see the structure of the tables. Do you have a Calendar table that joins the two tables?

Thank you I managed to sort using a related table
